# How to open MDCard when I press a button in kivy(python)?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a button on a screen, I want to open ***MDCard*** when I press this button. I wrote this code the same as ***Popup*** but the ***MDCard*** object has no attribute 'open'. How can I open *MyMDCard*

```
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Second>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"Open MDCard"
            size_hint: .3, .07 
            pos_hint: {"x":.07, "y":0.25} 
            on_release: Factory.MyMDCard().open()

<MyMDCard@MDCard>
    orientation: "vertical"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'Blue.png'

    FloatLayout:    
        Button:
            id: 'change'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MDCard` is not a `Popup`, it is just another `Widget`. So to display the `MDCard`, you must add it to your `App` typically by using the `add_widget()` method of some container that is already in your `App`. For example, instead of:

```
on_release: Factory.MyMDCard().open()
```

try:

```
on_release: root.add_widget(Factory.MyMDCard())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But another question. What command should I enter if I want to close this widget with one button?

Comment: You can do that by saving a reference to the `MyMDCard` and calling `remove_widget()` to remove it from display. But you are describing exactly what `Popup` is intended for. Consider using a `Popup` that contains your `MyMDCard`, then you can simply use `open()` and `dismiss()`.

Comment: I put `remove_widget()` in the corresponding function. I got the error `name 'remove_widget' is not defined`. Indeed I only have one button inside `MDCard` that, when pressed, returns a number in its corresponding function and another button to close `MDcard`.

Comment: You must use the `remove_widget()` method of the same container that has the `add_widget()` that you used.

Comment: I have a problem, Should I use `ids` for `remove_widget()`?

Comment: I wrote `on_release: root.remove_widget(Factory.BlankMDCard())`   for close Button, but not worked.

Comment: You are not understanding basic concepts of Python. I suggest studying the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
on_release:app.root.current = "Name of the Widget"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?